# How to use Azure Mobile Services or Notification Hub to send Push Notification to a specific user?

Tags: azure

Can anyone suggest me how to use the **Azure Mobile Services** or the **Notification Hub** to **send push notification to a specific user**? Please suggest with respect to a **Store App** (**not** Windows Phone Silverlight App).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a notion of userId in your app. So registering device in the Notification Hub specify that userId as a tag. Then you can specify that tag sending a message and that message will be delivered to desired user only.

Some tutorials:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530749.aspxa

Comment: I tried the following code for registering the app to the notification hub:     var hub = new NotificationHub("<hub name>", "<connection string with listen access>");              
    var result = await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(channel.Uri);          Where should I include the tag to specify the userId?

Comment: There is overload for this method: RegisterNativeAsync(String, IEnumerable<String>). Where second argument is a list of tags, pass your user id there.